# Dynamic Sitemap PHP / XML

Tags: php, sql, xml, sitemap

I need a Dynamic Sitemap for my Dynamic PHP SQL Website, than I searched and followed a tutorial.

But when I submit it, there is an error:

"error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

I search about ii and I realized that this is because of the short tags of PHP

But I can´t take the Short Tags Function off, because I use that in my whole website.

Then I need another solution;

That´s my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');
error_reporting(0);
include "connection.php";
$hoje = date('Y-m-d');

  $output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  echo $output
?>
<urlset
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">


// Here goes my Normal Sitemap //


// Here goes my Dynamic Sitemap //
    <?php
$sql_tabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE codigoImovel != '1' ORDER BY idImovel DESC");
$sql_tabela1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prontomorar WHERE idPronto != '1' ORDER BY idPronto DESC");
$sql_tabela2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM construcao WHERE idConstrucao != '1' ORDER BY idConstrucao DESC");

    ?>
</urlset>
```

I tried to use that:

```
echo file_get_contents( "data.txt" );
```

with this content in "data.txt":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But, this didn´t help me at all;

So, anyone can help me????

Comment: If you do not have any rule against, you might omitt the `<?xml ...?>` declaration completely...

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: How do you say omitt??? And what output dou refer to??

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in another Forum how to solve it;

I have saved my file in a different type of file.

It should be just UTF-8 and I saved something else;

So, just save it as UTF-8 your PHP File;